# xcode７のナビゲーターエリアにストーリーボードもビューコントローラーも表示されない。

Tags: swift

初心者です。タイトル通りのことが起こり作業が中断しています。心当たりは
ありません。お手数おかけいたしますが解決策をご教授ください。

Comment: ナビゲーターエリアのアイコンが並んでいるヘッダー部の左端にあるフォルダー型のアイコン(マウスオーバーで`Show the Project navigator`と表示されるやつ)は選択された状態(青い太線表示)になっていますか?

Comment: そのプロジェクトがすでに別のプロジェクトから開かれてる、とかも考えられますが（プロジェクトを開いたままワークスペースを開いたりするとそうなります）推測するにも情報が足りないですね。表示されないと言っても色々な状態が考えられますので、どうなっているのかスクリーンショットなどで見せてもらえませんか？